# Check if process is a plugin

Tags: powershell

I want to check with Powershell if the process called "jp2launcher" is a plugin or not. I have the following command for the commandline:

```
wmic process where (name="jp2launcher.exe") get CommandLine
```

The result of this command is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\jp2launcher.exe" -secure -plugin ...
```

So if there is `-plugin` the process is a plugin. Is there a way to select only the processes which are plugins?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you question but can't you just filter the command? Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | where { $_.CommandLine -ne $null -and $_.CommandLine.Contains("-plugin") } |
 select commandline

Comment: This works for me fine, but where do I have to set the selection on the name "jp2launcher"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is there a way to select only the processes which are plugins ?*

This will query WMI for processes with a command line matching the string "-plugin" (and select fields Name and CommandLine only) :

`Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where CommandLine -match "-plugin" | Select Name, CommandLine`

*How can I now select only the process which are called "jp2launcher", and how can I save their process ID into a variable?*

`Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where CommandLine -match "-plugin" | Where Name -match "jp2launcher" | Select Name, CommandLine`

Comment: How can I now select only the process which are called "jp2launcher", and how can I save their process ID into a variable?

Comment: Added another example based on your request. I assumed you wanted the name AND command line match.